# Is there a word or phrase that describes old articles published again?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Say there is a journal that publishes new articles every month. But now say the journal decides to dedicate a section to include very old articles from years ago. The journal might decide to do this because these articles were very popular when they were published years ago and wants to give its new readers an opportunity to read those articles.

Is there a word or phrase that describes such articles?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Two commonly used terms:

Reprint

From the Archives

Comment: "Reprint" has a different meaning, at least in academic publishing: it refers to complementary printed copies of a journal article sent to the author at the time of initial publication, so they can distribute them to colleagues.

Answer (score 14):

They are **republications**

OED:

> **3. a. The action of publishing a work again; the fact of being republished.**
>
> 1995   Wired June 200/2   *Electronic publishers should allow anybody to republish their materials, provided that republication takes place by means of a pointer to the original document.*
>
> **b. A new publication of a work; a work that has been published again.**
>
> 1796   W. Withering Arrangem. Brit. Plants (ed. 3) I. Pref. 5   *This may rather be regarded as a new work than as a re-publication of an old one.*
>
> 2002   N. Nicolson Fanny Burney vii. 108   *Fanny Burney's name suffered only intermittent eclipse, and in recent years it has shone again with the republication of all her novels.*

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to feature articles from a specific milestone year(s) and even specific month in the past. *Scientific American* does this.

> [ENGINEERING: **50, 100 & 150 Years Ago**: February 2021](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/50-100-150-years-ago-february-2021/)

This approach and style of rubric/issue naming is fascinating for technology and the sciences, where progress is so fast.

In addition to a regular magazine, journal, or newspaper feature taking this approach, anthologies are sometimes published separately:

> [*The Washington post*: **The first 100 years**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0395258545)